# Would water spill from a bowl in a Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

If I put a full Bowl of Commanding Water Elementals in a Bag of Holding, would the bowl spill?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### There's no rules about Bag of Holding and spilling, but that's not saying much.

Bag of Holding is a very RP-heavy item, and the properties of the bag change with each DM. Some DMs have a bag of holding as a walk in closet, others treat the space inside as a floating void. And none of them are wrong.

Bag of Holding is one of those things in D&D where it's left intentionally vague about how it works, because it's supposed to make gameplay simpler, help deal with all the pocket searching and carry limits that can bog down late game play. Adding rules to it is somewhat counterproductive.

There's nothing in any official rules or errata, but me personally, assuming you're not doing anything to cause the bowl to spill as you put it in, there shouldn't be anything that causes the bowl to spill once inside. One of the few actual rules is that the stored items are on a separate plane, so no amount of bumping the bag would affect it.

Answer (score 11):

This will be a DM-decision.

If I were the DM, the answer would be no. I would assume that the "holding" property of the Bag Of Holding would have some kind of magical "support" baked into it.

However, this will be a DM by DM decision, so the only answer would be "ask the DM."

If you *are* the DM, then it's up to you... Just be certain to keep your decision consistent throughout future play.

Comment: I agree it’s DM’s decision, but one thing to think about in making the decision is why the character wants to do this.  Keeping a Bowl of Commanding Water Elementals full while placing it somewhere it cannot spill implies a desire to maintain control of the Elemental without the usual risk the item entails.  If you’re going to let the bowl not spill inside the Bag of Holding, then you might also want to rule that placing it there breaks the control because the Bowl is no longer on the same plane.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with [Snarflcat's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141787/would-water-spill-from-a-bowl-in-a-bag-of-holding/141789#141789) that the contents of the bowl wouldn't spill, my reasoning is very different:  The space inside any such magical storage space is at most only marginally connected to the normal realm the characters occupy.  What happens to the outside of the container doesn't happen to the inside.  There's no need for any magical restraint of the held items; they aren't being subjected to force in the first place.